# Polymorphism using interface and abstract class

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

```
abstract class B extends A implements C {

// why I have to add implementation here for add() function


}
class A{
    void add(){        
    }
}
interface C{
    void add();

}
```

I was expecting that I don't need to implement the `add()` method in abstract class `B`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

a quirk of interfaces is that all members they contain are *inherently* `public`. Whereas in classes, they are inherently package private. (as in: if you do not specify an access modifier (`public`, `private`, or `protected`) - in interfaces then the thing is `public`, in classes, they are package private).

Hence, the `add()` in `class A` is package private, and the `add()` in `interface C` is public. You can't lower access levels - if you implement C, your `void add()` method **must** also be `public` (or any higher access level, but `public` is already the highest).

If you make that `add()` in your `A` class `public`, all will be well.

Note that the error you got is:

```
Test.java:1: error: add() in A cannot implement add() in C
abstract class B extends A implements C {
         ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
1 error
```

Which really says it all, no? For future reference, when asking questions on SO, you should include stuff like this. Errors aren't voodoo magic written in martianese. You can read them, they tend to point at the problem.